# Aster Data belongs to which Database family

Tags: analytics, bigdata, teradata-aster

I know Aster Data leverages SQL Map Reduce, ncluster and analytic capability.
From Database architecture perspective which family does Aster belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aster database doesn't formally belong to certain database family, but you can identify it with several database types:

- it's distributed, parallel, relational database;
- it's MPP (massively parallel processing) database;
- it's based on PostgreSQL open source code (forked);
- it's NOT based on Teradata database.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly about right name, but it is sharded db, what means one Queen server and several workers with running postgres instances.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with topchef. Hope the below gives you some high level information.

- The database is built on top of Postgres similar to other databases like Netezza and Greenplum.
- Asterdata is built on postgres but in a distributed manner.
- It has something called vproc's which are similar to a standalone postgres db instance.
- A Node (worker) will have multiple vprocs and all the nodes are co-ordinated using a Queen node (Master).
- Though its built on Postgres, not all features of postgres are ported to Asterdata because of the distributed nature of the system.